# Handling click event on items inside listview item

Tags: android, listview, onclick, adapter, getview

I have a custom list view in which each item has two buttons(ADD & SUB) and a textView which maintains a count.

Initially the count is zero, when I click ADD button it adds 1 and subtracts 1 when I click on SUB button.

Since for each row the count should be maintain separately, I am not finding any technique through which I can do the same.

I tried using View.OnClickListener inside my adapter but wasn't able to retrieve the position. Due to this whenever I clicked on ADD button, it adds 1 to every item.

Please help me with some useful technique.

Answer (score 6):

First you have to make ViewHolder class which holds all the TextView and Button of your listview items. After that make object ViewHolder and by that holder object initialize all values like TextView and Button in getView. By using this techniques values not repeated in all rows.

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>{
LayoutInflater vi;  
LinearLayout l;
Activity c;
String i[];
ArrayList<Integer> n;
ViewHolder holder;


public CustomAdapter(Activity context, String[] i) {
    super(context,R.layout.list_item, i);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    this.c = context;
    this.i = i;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = c.getLayoutInflater();
        convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.imageview = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.img);
        holder.btnAdd = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.inc);
        holder.txt = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt);
        holder.l = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.linear);

        holder.btnAdd.setTag(holder);
        convertView.setTag(holder);

        holder.btnAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            int count=0;

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                View p = (View) v.getParent();
                ViewHolder holder1 = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
                count = Integer.valueOf(holder1.txt.getText().toString());
                count++;
                holder1.txt.setText(String.valueOf(count));



            }
        });

    }

            return convertView;
}

static class ViewHolder {
    public ImageView imageview;
    public Button btnAdd;
    public TextView txt;
    public LinearLayout l;
 }
}
```

Comment: Using this way, it will take the last set value for other list items. Because getView called only once till you scroll your view. Once you scroll you view, getView called again and counter starts from zero whereas for other items which are already visible, onclicking add button it takes last updated value from other items.

Answer (score 0):

in the `getView` method of your adapter, just before setting the click listener, you can retain the current position by creating a final variable initialized with the parameter `position` from `getView`. Then in the click listener, you can use it.

Comment: I used click listener inside getView and called another function with 'position' passed as parameters. But the question is how can I use that position with holder object to increase the count for that particular row. I do not find any function to make use of position outside getView using holder object.

Comment: then pass the holder to your function Oo

Answer (score 0):

First you have to maintain a Array, which should be updated as per your addition and subtraction. Now, you can put onClick listener of your add and sub button in adapter like this,

```
holder.plus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String a = holder.quantity.getText().toString();
                Integer qua = Integer.parseInt(a) + 1;
                String q = qua.toString();
                holder.quantity.setText(q);
                //update in database.
                // In above comment you update the database. Now at this place you need to set the "q" to your list which you passed to adapter
                yourList.get(position).setQuantity(q); // here you can set the updated value to your list which automatically reflect to your listview
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

set click listener in your adapter to your reference object where you have save the button reference

```
listHolder.buttonAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // Do the adding task here
    }
});
```

it will trigger against your list item add button only without disturbing others